# Mean Stack Root Routing is not working

Tags: express, mean-stack, express-router

Can someone help me why default route is not working in my Mean App, But the next routing works

Here when I open **http://localhost:3000** I am not able to see any output, But I have defined route in route.js which is working

```
   var express = require('express');
   var cors = require('cors');
   var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var path = require('path');

    const port = 3000;

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Test');
        console.log('Opened the root path');
    });
```

When I open the page with **http://localhost:3000/main** I am able to see the Output and also log written in the console

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/main', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is the Admin Landing Page');
});

router.get('/install', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is the Install Landing Page');
    console.log('Opened the Install  path');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you the code you pasted is the full version, and it's not runnable because:

1. You did not declare `app` variable.
2. You did not `start the http server`.

It's really hard to tell the root cause what's wrong of your code. Following codes works for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3000;

let app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Test');
    console.log('Opened the root path');
});

let server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

Comment: But Is there anything wrong I am doing in my code Just wanted to understand what it's making not to run

Comment: Sorry I didn't define entire code here , I had initialized the `app` and also started the HTTP server using `nodemon`

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error and I feel that method is not calling at all because I am not getting anything in the console logs as well when I open `http://localhost:3000` I just see blank screen

Comment: If you shutdown the server, you will get `404`, right?